# Como verificar se o usuário está online no momento?

Tags: mysql, asp

É o seguinte, fiz um sistema onde o administrador pode ver os usuários onlines no momento e deslogar eles. Até aí tudo bem, criei uma variavel na tabela usuario no mysql que fica TRUE quando o usuário loga e FALSE quando ele desloga, o problema é se o usuário fechar a página sem deslogar, pois ele vai estar offline mas não vai fazer o update para ficar com o valor FALSE no banco.

Alguma Sugestão do que devo fazer?

OBS: Estou desenvolvendo em ASP Clássico

Answer (score -2):

Apenas registre um evento a ser executado antes de fechar a janela e dentro do evento faça uma chamada no servidor usando ajax, por exemplo, e atualize a tabela no banco.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) { 
       // seu codigo aqui 
    };
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

Comment: Caso caia a energia elétrica, ou trave o sistema e seja necessário reiniciar a máquina desligando-a da tomada, será que o Ajax é chamado?

Answer (score -2):

Tive um problema desse tempos atrás e fiz o seguinte: criei uma tabela para informar os usuários que se logam no sistema (serve até de log de acesso). Bom, a cada "logada", a tabela recebe um registro informando data e hora, data hora da última transação e ID do navegador (e o login, claro). Ao passo de cada transação, esse registro é atualizado. Caso o usuário fique por algum tempo sem executar uma transação esse é tido como offline. Se quiser derrubar o usuário, basta que cada transação verifique a sinalização que pode ser editada por um moderador...

Answer (score -2):

No seu caso a forma mais correta (sem gambiarras) é utilizar o evento "Session_OnEnd" do arquivo global.asa. Na página de login crie uma variável de sessão com o código do usuário logado (ex: Session("UserId")) e no evento Session_OnEnd do global.asa, se a variável de sessão existir, atualize o banco de dados com a informação que o respectivo usuário não está mais logado. Também é interessante definir uma Session.TimeOut com o tempo que deseja que cada sessão fique disponível.

Obs: Essa é a melhor solução se o usuário fechar a página sem clicar no botão para deslogar, porém irá demorar alguns minutos até o sistema entender que a sessão terminou e atualizar o banco de dados. Então utilize ela juntamente com a solução que já usa atualmente, atualizando o banco de dados quando o cliente clicar para deslogar.

Nesse link tem mais detalhes de sua utilização dos eventos do arquivo global.asa (em português): http://www.superasp.com.br/paginas_exibir_detalhes.asp?dep=0,0&id=36

Espero ter ajudado!